# How to do incremental builds with Webpack, across each invocation from the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When I run `webpack` from command line, it just builds everything from scratch. How can we make Webpack do incremental builds across invocations of `webpack` CLI, so that it parses and transpiles only files that have changed?

I'd like for this to work *across each invocation of `webpack`* without a long-running process.

`webpack --watch` and `webpack-dev-server` are not options because they stay running, which I don't want.

For example, I want to run `webpack` and it will exit, then the next time I run `webpack` I would like it to be smart and not rebuild everything all over, just rebuild changed files.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible yet?
Seems like an old issue but I can't find the solution anywhere. If so, it would be great to have it in this post, since this is the first stackoverflow post I got addressing this issue.

Comment: Vite is aiming to address this. https://vitejs.dev/

Comment: @Robert Is Vite built on Webpack?

Comment: @trusktr It's built on Rollup

Comment: I am facing the same issue here. Did you managed to find any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not incremental per-se, but webpack 5 introduced build cache: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/ (see also related issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6527)

Just add the following to `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  cache: {
    type: 'filesystem'
  },
};
```

Running a small benchmark on my application, build time with cache is cut by about 55-80%

Note however this feature is not recommended for CI use at the moment. See for example https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13291

Comment: I can confirm that, just by adding the snippet above, we had a huge improvement in our build time, going 10-20x times faster.

Comment: Nice speedup for me to (even when using HMR with --watch). Also worth taking a look at the [`maxAge`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cachemaxage) attribute to prevent an overwhelming amount of disk usage.

Answer (score -1):

This is about webpack 1.x but should be the same for 2.x:

[Build Performance > Incremental Build](https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html):

> Make sure you don’t do a full rebuild. Webpack has a great caching layer that allows you to keep already compiled modules in memory. There are some tools that help to use it:
>
> `webpack-dev-server`: Serves all webpack assets from memory. Best performance.
> `webpack-dev-middleware`: The same performance as webpack-dev-server for advanced users.
> `webpack –watch` or `watch: true`: Caches stuff but write assets to disk. Ok performance.

They don't mention *incremental build* explicitly in the docs of 2.x, but they still mention the the caching in [Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My requirement is that no process is left running. Id like to run `webpack` and it will exit, then the next time I run `webpack` it won't do a full rebuild. `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack –watch` leave the process running. What about `webpack-dev-middleware`? Can we have incremental builds without leaving a running process using `webpack-dev-middleware`?

Answer (score -2):

I highly recommend webpack --watch.
"When using watch mode, webpack installs file watchers to all files, which were used in the compilation process. If any change is detected, it’ll run the compilation again. When caching is enabled, webpack keeps each module in memory and will reuse it if it isn’t changed."

- https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My requirement is that no process is left running, but watch mode leave webpack running. I just need to run `webpack`, then the next time I run `webpack` I'd like for it not to do a full build all over again.

Comment: This appears to be an option issue for webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/250